# Can't setup GoogleSignIn. I'm getting ApiException: 8

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

1. I've created project in Google Cloud Console and simple OAuth 2.0 Client IDs credentials. Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs are empty
2. I've written code like in several manuals:

```
    val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken("Client ID from previous step")
        .requestEmail()
        .requestScopes(Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE), Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
        .build()
    val mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, signInOptions)

    try {
        val gIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
        val account = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(gIntent).await()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(LOG_BACKUP_TAG, "Can't login to google", e)
        if (e is CancellationException) throw e
    }
```

But I'm getting

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Error code 8 (INTERNAL_ERROR) is general and you may need to check several components. Make sure you double check your app registration in the dev console. Note that every registered Android client is uniquely identified by the (package name, Android Signing Certificate SHA-1) pair.  Open the Credentials page and choose your project. Verify that every pair has an Android typed OAuth 2.0 client IDs.

If you need to create a new OAuth 2.0 client ID for your Android client, select **New Credentials->OAuth2 Client ID** from the dropdown, select Android and input your Package name / Signing-certificate fingerprint there.

Here are commands to get your signing key certificate SHA-1:

For Standard Debug Key:

*‘keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android’*

For Custom Key:

*‘keytool -list -v -keystore $YOUR_KEYSTORE_LOCATION’*